Manhwa where the main character's family is deleted by the system next to the place where they lived
I had read this manhwa in Manga Livre a long time ago. The manhwa was colorful.
If I remember correctly he was an ordinary person who gains powers. The most memorable scene was him coming home and there was a huge hole where the his family's apartment was and everything was deleted by the system. Later on he discovers that it was someone's desire/power that caused it.
